# PHP Query Updated Rows Count

Tags: opencart

I am a .NET programmer and rarely work with PHP. How can I tell if this query fails or if this query updates 0 rows? I am using OpenCart:

```
public function updateInventory($product_id, $quantity)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("Update " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET quantity ='" . $this->db->escape($quantity) . "' WHERE sku='" . $this->db->escape($product_id) . "'");
    return "OK";

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replacing

```
 return "OK";
```

with (depends on libraries you use to connect with database. mysql , mysqli or pdo)

```
return mysql_affected_rows();
```

will get you the affected rows. That is from PHP code side. Opencart has a default function that you can use: `$this->db->countAffected()`

but i am not sure if they have kept it the same through different versions.

source : https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Hope everything is clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have no updated quantity for the product because you are comparing SKU and product_id in your query.

If you want to update product quantity by product_id, you need to change your expression to this one:

```
'UPDATE `' . DB_PREFIX . 'product` SET `quantity` =' . (int)$quantity . ' WHERE `product_id`= " . (int)$product_id
```

"WHERE **product_id** = some_product_id" instead of "WHERE **sku** = some_product_id"

Comparing `SKU` with `product_id` in `WHERE` statement is the reason why your query updates 0 rows.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I know any rows are updated? Is there a count method?

Comment: Sorry, I was offline, and Jonid Bendo already gave you answer about `mysql_affected_rows` function.